# How to find max int in an array, while ignoring all numbers greater than first value?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Having trouble with this problem on an assignment I'm working on. I believe the problem is that the method will never return a negative value, but I'm not sure why that is or how to fix it. (Also, this has to be done using recursion, even though that is probably the worst way to accomplish it.

```
private static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numList, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNum) {
    if(startIndex>-1&&startIndex<100){
        if(startIndex==endIndex){
            if(numList[startIndex]<=firstNum){
                return numList[startIndex];
            } else {
                return 222; //number used for testing
            }
        }
        if(numList[startIndex]>=
        findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numList,startIndex+1,endIndex,firstNum) &&
        numList[startIndex]<=firstNum){         
            return numList[startIndex];
        } else {
            return findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numList,startIndex+1,endIndex,firstNum);
        }
    } return 333; //number used for testing
}
```

The goal is to return the integer in the array that is largest while ignoring all of the numbers that are larger than numList[0].

Comment: if you ignore all elements larger than numList[0] then isn't numList[0] the largest? or do you want to find the largest of all numbers which are less than numList[0]

Comment: Hint: You can try to sort your list. Unless of course your assignments requires a recursive solution.

Comment: 1. Have to use recursion

Comment: 2. I want to find the max of the numbers less than numList[0], excluding that value.

Comment: What are you supposed to do if the first value is the minimum of the array, so there are no other values amongst which to find the maximum?

Comment: I believe in that case you would return the "firstNum" value, however that was not the case for any of the test cases I had to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numList, int currentIndex, int len, int currentMax) {
    // when you reach the end of the array, return the currentMax
    if (currentIndex == len - 1) {
        return currentMax;
    }
    int firstElement = numList[0];
    // if the current element we are looking at in this stage of the recursion is greater
    // than the first element, ignore it and recurse on the next element
    if (numList[currentIndex] >= firstElement) {
        return findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numList, currentIndex + 1, len, currentMax);
    }
    int newMax;
    // if none of the previous conditions were true, and this current value is greater than
    // the currentMax, update the currentMax
    if (numList[currentIndex] > currentMax) {
        newMax = numList[currentIndex];
    }
    return findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numList, currentIndex + 1, len, newMax);
}
```

When you call this function, set your currentMax to something like the minimum integer value. This way you can check the return value at the end to see if you did, in fact, have an element less than the first element.

Comment: Thank you! However, one of the other rules for the assignment was that you're not allowed to use static variables.

Comment: You mean local variables within the method? I.e. you cannot declare 'int firstElement = numList[0]' ?

Comment: If that is what you mean, just get rid of those lines and put them in the actual conditions / method. I only made some local variables so that the code would be more readable.

Comment: That is how I understood it, but I may be mistaken. The exact line was "If these methods are implemented using a Loop or any Static Variable, points will be deducted (from the test cases) even if your program passes test cases. DO NOT use any Static Variables."

Comment: Static is different from local. You should change the method definition so that is does not say 'private static int' and instead just says 'private int'. But take a look at this in the meantime: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html

Comment: There are NO static variables in this answer

Comment: When I delete the "static" in the method declaration, I get an error in the main method saying "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ..."

Comment: Welp, that is pretty self explanatory. I assume your main method is static (which it probably should be), and you are trying to call a non-static method within it.